# Multiple GPU training with tensorfow.slim.learning

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

The new learning module in tensorflow.contrib.slim looks very promising :
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py
I'm trying to figure out how can I reproduce the CIFAR 10 multi-gpu example (or the ImageNet example) using this new module on a configuration where I have only a single worker node but with several GPU on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim/deployment
When creating the config object you would set num_clones = [num_gpus]

For example,

```
config = model_deploy.DeploymentConfig(num_clones=2)
```

Check out the example in model_deploy.py file.